# Are there fundamental differences between finite and infinite systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, regularization, degrees-of-freedom, lattice-model

Most sources on classical field theory introduce classical fields as a limit of a system with $N$ particles constrained in some way in a lattice where a continuum limit involving $N$, lattice size and spacing is taken to arrive at the field theory. In this context it seems intuitively obvious to me that for any physical system describable with lagrangian mechanics the question "Do I really need infinitely many degrees of freedom?" can not be answered by experiment. In particular, given some maximum accuracy of measurements of basic observables one can find a finite-degree-of-freedom system for any field theory and a field theory for a system with sufficiently many particles that are not distinguishable. Discretization is a tool used a lot in numerics and I've never heard of fundamental limitations of discretization to solve continuum-type problems. Of course I wonder if my intuition is true here.

In the same style, in any concrete field theory it shouldn't matter if space is taken to be infinitely large or a finite box with some boundary conditions, as long as that box is large enough. For measurements with finite accuracy such systems such be indistinguishable. In a quantum theory experiment should not be able to distinguish between a system that is well described using a finite dimensional Hilbert space and one that is well described by using an infinite dimensional one. Summing up: I'm asking if there is any fundamental meaning/significance to the following kinds of infinities:

1. Infinite number of degrees of freedom in field theories
2. Infinite extension of space (and perhaps time)
3. The need to use infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces in Quantum Mechanics

The remainder of this question ponders my initial thoughts and addresses some arguments I'm expecting to hear. As I said above, I believe the number of degrees of freedom does not have fundamental significance. Any system that is well described by a field theory can also be described using finitely many degrees of freedom. I believe this to be true both in classical and in quantum theories while of course not having an argument or even a precise formulation of the claim.

I'm not quite so sure about the infinite space. Again, physical intuition suggests that for observations of finite duration within a limited regions of space it shouldn't matter what is going on very far away from this region. Hence I believe the second infinity also doesn't have any fundamental significance. I'm not worried on a fundamental level about discretization breaking desired symmetries as long as there are approximations to said symmetries which still hold.Both methods of dealing with with infinities are used in quantum field theory: Lattice QFT strictly speaking studies systems with finitely many degrees of freedom confined to bounded regions of space. I'm wondering about how much these ideas can help in defining interacting quantum field theories rigorously and whether it helps answer the question "can it always be done" positively.

I also do not believe that one really needs infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces but I'm least sure of this claim. I want to try to address some arguments I'm expecting from those that claim one obviously does need infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces:

- "Finite dimensional Hilbert spaces have no scattering theory" (Scattering operators never exist). I don't believe without further arguments that it's a problem to have periodicity under time evolution of any state (which is why you don't get scattering states because nothing just keeps flying off to "infinity") as long as that recurrence time is long enough.
- "No commutation relations in finite dim. Hilbert spaces". I'm not convinced this is obviously a problem. For one, you can't have (canonical) commutation relations with bounded operators but those are used in the algebraic approaches to quantum physics. On the other hand, the only thing a quantum theory REALLY needs to do is predict probability distributions for observables to arbitrary desired precision (maybe that's even already asking too much). I believe bounded operators on finite dimensional Hilbert spaces can do this without meaningful changes to the formalism. On the other hand, one can discretize PDEs, which should correspond to finding approximations to relations between unbounded operators expressed by matrices.